# How to Save Recorded Audio file in application's raw folder

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I have to record the voice and save it and later play the same. I want to save the recorded audio in the raw folder of the application. How should I give the the directory path of raw folder to save my Audio file.

Comment: Are u trying to save this file to sdcard or directly on the phone?

Comment: No I don't want to save the file on SD card bcoz a device may or may not have SD card.I am trying to save the file in res/raw folder of my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you can't.

Because of `Android .apk file is read-only`, you can't write any file in package hierarchy (like res, raw, asset).

Better to store it in application's package (internal storage) or External Storage.

**Update:**

This will create a file in application's internal storage.

```
//content is base64 string you can use directly use FileInputstream's byte
byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(content, 0);
//filePath just filename of your audio file this will create a file in /data/data/<package_name>/files
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filePath, Context.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
fos.close();
```

Comment: For your need /data/data/<package_name>/files is useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't re-write resources after building the app. Best thing you can do with files placed in resources is read them into memory,modify them maybe, and save the results to sdcard or some other provided storage area. Files created by your application are also removed when your application gets un-installed, so need to worry.

To save to sdcard, try something like this:

You need the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then you can send in the data and the filename:

```
public void saveFileToCard(byte[] data,String filename) {
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
   FileOutputStream fos;
   try {
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
   }
}
```

This, or a variation of it should help you i think.